# Outputting other content types; besides HTML with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to have a stand alone app output any other content-type besides HTML.  i.e. if I wanted to output plain text so it could be consumed by another app (creating a simple web service)?

Comment: In short, the answer is yes.  You many need to provide more information if you want a better answer.

Comment: Sure, glad to.  Basically I have an opt-out form that populates a single column in a spreadsheet. I want the script to run as a web service and accept an email address as an arg (i.e http://url?address=joe@foo.com ) .  I then want a plain text response of 1 or 0 if it exists in the list or not. It's a simple script that works fine with HTML output, but I'm missing how to do a plain text response.

Answer (score 4):

This week we launched the ContentService, which allows you to return content in formats such as JSON, ATOM, and plain text.

```
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Hello World')
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

Comment: Use apps script all the time & excited by the new features unveiled at I/O!